# linux socket server stops abruptly

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to write a socket based client/server program, which can exchange message continuously. I'm coming across a problem.  The server program stops abruptly after 1 or 2 messages are received from client, and just doesn't continue further.  Can you please let me know what could be going wrong ?  The internals of socket code is roughly based on the stream socket server/client given in [beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html).

My server code:

```
void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
 //       while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
          wait(NULL);
} 

int main()
{
    int numbytes;
    u32 size = 0;
    s8 buf[1024] = "Hello World";
    s8 recvbuff[1024];
    cpl_Socket s1("127.0.0.1","3490",E_ServerSocket);
    s1.registerSocket();
    s1.listenOnPort();
        sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) 
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
    cpl_Socket newFd;
        struct sigaction sa;
    while(1)
    {
        if ( newFd.acceptConn(s1.getSocketFd()) != e_success)
        {
            LOG(warn,"Accept Error");
            continue;
        }
        if (!fork())
        {
            close(s1.getSocketFd());
            size = (u32)strlen(buf);
            numbytes = newFd.SocketTx(buf,size);
            if (numbytes < 0)
            {
                perror("Write");
                LOG(fatal,"Write to Socket Failed\n");
            }
            LOG(info, "Server sent[%s], bytes [%d]\n",buf,numbytes);
            while (1)
            {
                                cout <<"Child here\n";
                numbytes = newFd.SocketRx(recvbuff,sizeof(recvbuff));
                LOG(info, "Server received[%s], bytes[%d]\n", buf,numbytes);
                cout <<"Enter string to send to client:";
                cin >> recvbuff;
                newFd.SocketTx(recvbuff,strlen(recvbuff));
            }
        }
                cout <<"Back to parent\n";
        close(newFd.getSocketFd());
    }
        cout <<"Back to parent again\n";
        wait(NULL);
    close(s1.getSocketFd());
    return(0);
}
```

Sample of my server output given below:

```
    CommonUtils$ [[DEBUG]][comm_ipc.cpp:acceptConn():149]->
    New connection from 127.0.0.1 received on socket 4

    Server sent[Hello World], bytes [11]
    Server received[hi], bytes[1048576]
    Enter string to send to client:k
    k: command not found

    [1]+  Stopped                 ./server

    [1]+  Stopped                 ./server
```

Comment: did you really sent 1048576 bytes?  your buffer size is only 1024 bytes... I guess you didn't check for errors.

Comment: No i did not, that's another bug i'm trying to resolve ! Like it shows, the only string it received was "hi", but somehow the no. of bytes received is screwed up.  Here's my recv function, if it helps:                                                           `s32 cpl_Socket::SocketRx(s8 *buf, u32 size)
{
 assert(sockfd != INIT_SOCKFD);
 return (recv(sockfd,buf,size,0));
}`

Comment: check the `send` return value, is it possible you gave the buffer size instead of the data size?

Comment: What exactly does 'LOG(info, "Server received[%s]' do?  Also 'strlen(recvbuff)'.

Comment: Fork returns a negative number if it fails.  Make sure you are checking for that.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, i found that tif I remove the cin/scanf from the code, the code works as expected.  Although I'm not sure why.  Is there any restrictions on reading stdin in a child process ?